# Problem facing with multibyte characters while unzipping in linux

Tags: linux, unix, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

we are recieving a zip file from a source system. It is a .zip file.
we are unzipping it in linux using unzip command. the .zip file contains a .dat file which contains lines which are of same width. To be precise , it is a fixed width file. But while unzipping , extra characters are getting added to the .dat file which causes difference in the length of different lines.

```
 unzip edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20181021.182305.zip
```

this produces edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20181021.182305.dat

```
grep -P -n -a "[\x00-\x1F]"  edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20181021.182305.dat | wc -l
467
```

This shows that there are special characters in 467 lines as per the design.
I have opened the bad.dat file in vi and found special characters.
Ex:

```
@^@^R^@
^A^@
<90>^@^@^@


 grep -P -n -a "[\x00-\x1F]"  edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20181021.182305.dat  > bad.dat
    awk '{ print length($0) }' bad.dat | sort | uniq
    2090
    2091
    2092
    2219
    2220
    2221
    2222
    2223
    2224
    2225
```

2219 is the correct length.
This implies , the presence of special characters can increase the number of character or decrease the number of characters or don't change the number of characters.

we did a work around by replacing all the special characters with ?

```
perl -pe 's/[\000-\011]|[\013-\037]|[\177-\377]/?/g' edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20181021.182305.dat > clean.dat
```

as of now the problem is solved.

But I need to understand why special characters are inserted when unzip command is executed?.
Why do special characters changes the length of a line?. My understanding was that special character is considered as 1 character, but in this case its not.

File details.

```
 file -bi edw_ord_extr_3x_SIQP_20181021.182305.dat
    application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

I have opened the bad.dat file in notepad++ and is able to see special characters like SOH,BEL,NUL

[image]

Sample Hex Dump

```
000dff20  20 54 31 20 20 30 31 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  | T1  01         |
000e07d0  20 20 54 31 20 20 30 31  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |  T1  01        |
000e0e10  30 2e 30 30 30 30 30 30  58 5a 01 3f 00 00 00 00  |0.000000XZ.?....|
000e3340  20 30 39 30 30 20 20 54  31 20 20 30 31 20 20 20  | 0900  T1  01   |
000e4d60  31 20 20 30 31 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |1  01           |
000e78d0  30 30 20 20 54 31 20 20  30 31 20 20 20 20 20 20  |00  T1  01      |
000e7f20  00 00 01 00 52 4f 3f 20  20 20 20 46 41 4c 4c 42  |....RO?    FALLB|
000e8180  37 30 30 20 20 54 31 20  20 30 31 20 20 20 20 20  |700  T1  01     |
000e87d0  00 00 00 01 00 52 4f 3f  20 20 20 20 46 41 4c 4c  |.....RO?    FALL|
```

Comment: Can you show an example where an extra special character was added? Ideally with a hexdump (`xxd`).

Comment: your file might be ebcdic.. from mainframe ??

Comment: @choroba I have added screen shot and sample hex dump ...Please check if that helps.

Comment: @stack0114106 I guess its not from main frame. its coming from a database hosted on a unix box.

Comment: And it is most likely that field definitions in the remote database allow for multi-byte chars.  So the bad data is being inserted upstream, and if you can't get the upstream system to manage that, then your `sed` solution is as good as you can do. Else, search here for solutions for Unicode and UTF-8 (and others). Good luck!

Comment: AND It's not the `[NUL], [SOH], [BEL]` chars (they are just low value ascii s with no visual representation (`man ascii` please) ), it's the accent-grave `e` and umlated `u` that are multi-byte chars. (Sorry to French/German/Etc readers if I have not used the correct terminology ;-) ). Good luck to all.

Comment: @TomG: Thanks. Please identify the characters that were "added" in the samples.